# VBA getElementsByTagName not returning correct number of children

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm building a scraper in Excel VBA to pull data from [this link](https://www.mcmaster.com/screws/socket-head-screws/socket-head-screws-6/high-strength-316-stainless-steel-socket-head-screws/) at McMasterCarr.com.

```
'Sub McMaster2()
    Dim htmlTable As IHTMLElement
    Dim htmlRow As IHTMLElement
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ieObj As Object
    
    Set ieObj = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    
    ieObj.navigate "https://www.mcmaster.com/screws/" & _
                    "socket-head-screws/socket-head-screws-6/" & _
                    "high-strength-316-stainless-steel-socket-head-screws/"
                    
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    
    For Each htmlTable In ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("hn")
        For Each body In htmlTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
            Debug.Print body.childElementCount & " rows"
        Next body
    Next htmlTable
End Sub'
```

The immediate window shows 57 rows.
When I navigate to the webpage and check the DOM, it lists 80 rows.
[DOM screenshot clip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRfmK.png)

On further review, it appears 57 rows is the most it will return.  For instance, if you change the .navigate string to "https://www.mcmaster.com/screws/socket-head-screws/socket-head-screws-6/brass-socket-head-screws/", the immediate window reports 57 rows even though the DOM lists 123 children.

The upshot is I can only read in the first 57 rows of the table.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there something magic about 57?

Comment: There is nothing magic about 57 in this instance. ([42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)) is a totally different matter!) Rows are dynamically rendered. If you are able to access the appropriate scroll element and scroll to the bottom of the page, you will get the full count. You can test this with/without scrolling viewport on page and checking in console the row count. It may be that the scroll element is within shadow DOM and not accessible.

Comment: Right you are!  If I make the page visible and scroll to the bottom, then run the code it pulls all the data.